# How to do Online Refund in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.3, refund

On magento backend admin , on invoice tab there are two options , Refund and Refund Offline , I believe that clicking on Refund button will do online Refund and the money will be refunded back to the users account .can any one please give me some brief idea what am I missing ? do I need to do some code to make it refund online or magento will do it automatically . magento version 2.2.3

I had placed an order using paypal sandbox and than triggered online refund from admin backend invoice tab . but its showing We refunded $15.00 offline.  I believe it should be online refund .

Thanks is advance.